# Call function programmatically/"by string" in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic object property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name)

I have a function that I need to call based on a user inputted data.

So for example, I have:

```
models.cat
models.dog
```

Now, I want to be able to call `models.[my_str]` where `my_str = "snake"`.  So the computer would think it is trying to execute `models.snake`.  Is there a way to do this in javascript or better yet coffeescript?

Comment: How about `models.prototype[my_str]()`

Comment: `models[my_str]()` should work, yes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to call it like so:

```
models[my_str]();
```

This should work in both Javascript and Coffeescript.

Comment: perfect.  Works like a charm

Comment: You could also do `models[my_str].call()` which does the same thing, just has a different feel to it.